# AWS EC2 Tomcat Java Webapp - How can I manage bot http sessions

Tags: java, session, tomcat, amazon-ec2

I have a Tomcat 8 Java webapp deployed in an AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance.

It seems that there is a lot of bots trying to access my app because in my Javamelody monitoring I can see one-request bot's sessions cached by spring security like:

```
DefaultSavedRequest[http://52.27.73.101/phpmy-admin/]
DefaultSavedRequest[http://52.27.73.101/wp-login.php]
DefaultSavedRequest[http://52.27.73.101/admin/phpmyadmin/]
```

Is there a way to prevent from that bot's request? I don't know, maybe a spring security config that does not save them on caché, o a tomcat config that do something similar?

Lots of them doesn't have even IP, or Country, or User Agent.

Apart from security warning, my Javamelody Http Sessions Info it's not trustable because there are a lot of these.

The EC2 Instances is behind an AWS Load Balancer, so maybe can help in this thread too.

Comment: Assuming your app is internet facing app, you can't really avoid bots pinging/scanning your server (unless you really go with the approach of black listing IP's, which in my opinion requires lot of work). Ignore them, but make sure 1) you secure tomcat by creating users who can deploy/un-deploy apps. 2) Close any open non-required ports.

Comment: What is the target of your app? Maybe you could use a white list approach or even configure a PKI to allow traffic only to authenticated clients. As @kosa says if your app is open for all internet traffic the best you can do is harden your systems.

Comment: Yeah, is an internet facing app. Is open to the public who has an account. But they can't create accounts, only admins can.

But although my admin password are really strong, what I really want is to clear them because of my statistics aren't real with that sessions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an EC2 instance you have full control of your SO. You could use any tool, for example iptables, to control the network traffic. Maybe with something like this:

```
iptables -I INPUT -s <bot IP source> -j DROP
```

Comment: I am very amateur in linux usage. What would it do what are you proposing?

Comment: iptables acts as a packet filter and firewall. You can set a rule to deny http traffic from a certain host. https://www.linode.com/docs/security/firewalls/control-network-traffic-with-iptables

Comment: So i've added some info to the question, because there are lots of request of which I don't have Ip, User Agent, etc.